# ANT_ Introducing delay between each target

Tags: perl, ant, build.xml

I have an ant file with multiple targets `(task 1 , task 2, task3..)` I want to implement sleep between each target execution. I did that by introducing new target of `sleep` (it is Perl file execution contains sleep Perl script). Now, I called the target as:

```
target name="task1" description="XX" depends="sleep"
target name="task2" description="XX" depends="sleep"
```

When I do this, my sleep target is executed only once. It is not executing for all the targets. Please guide me to introduce sleep between each target.

Comment: Share the code with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to execute a [sleep](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sleep.html) Ant task at the start of each target:

```
<target name="targetX" description="xxx">
  <sleep seconds="2"/>
  ...
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You might be [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)**. You can set `$|` to 1 if you need unbuffered output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sleep` target is executed only once -- and this is the expected behaviour in Ant to avoid duplicate execution.

You can write a [BuildListener](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.9.3/org/apache/tools/ant/BuildListener.java#BuildListener).

Put `Thread.sleep(sleepTime)` in `targetFinished` method.